# What is the need for forms in Django?

Tags: javascript, python, django, django-forms

I am a noob in Python/Django and want to know what additional benefits Django forms offer compared to html forms? From what I have seen in a few tutorials, Django forms are mostly used for front-end validation only, which can also be done by html/JavaScript, so why should I use Django forms?

Comment: No, they are used for *backend* validation. Frontend validation is easily skipped, anyway.

Comment: Sorry if I was vague in the above question, what I meant to ask was, if I have a field that should be at least 10 characters long, why should I prefer Django forms if I can validate the same with html/JavaScript. Wouldn't using Django forms involve a round trip to the back-end and then to front-end again to display any error messages as against html where I can handle everything at the front end only?

Comment: Keeping in mind the above mentioned scenario, what are the advantages of using Django forms?

Comment: Sure. But any competent script kiddie could just use the browser dev tools to change the validation rules. You must always validate on the backend too.

Answer (score 2):

Front-end "validation" helps wrt/ UI/UX but is in no way a replacement for backend validation and sanitization. Well unless you're ok to have your sites and possibly the whole server being hacked by just any script-kiddie. Remember that "front end validation" only works in (some) browsers (and can be deactived) and that you can post requests without a browser (from a commandline utility like curl, from a Python or Perl or whatever script etc).

So you **do** need backend validation / sanitization whatever, and doing it right is hard - which is why most hand-coded PHP sites are like open bar to hackers.

Django's forms validation go *way* further than just checking text field's length, it supports all the needed sanitization, conversions from raw text values (what you get from the HTTP request) to proper Python types (including models instances), custom field validation thru custom validators and `clean_FIELD` hooks, cross-fields validations etc, as well as a standardized way to report validation errors to the user (showing *all* validation errors at once - most hand-coded form "validation" I've seen stop on the very first error, which is a sure way to make sure your user will give up in dispair). They also provide a standardized way to do front-end rendering without DRY violation (all the code - the form's fields, help texts, labels, error messages etc are defined once in the Form class). To make a long story short, using Django's forms, you encapsulate all the form's logic in a single place and reduce your view's code and template code to the bare minimum instead of having code scattered everywhere and repeating the same basic validations in each and every view.

Also, Django has `ModelForm` that greatly simplify creating/editing models (database records). Most of the validations are then derived from the model's definition itself, and sanitization will protect you from SQL injections etc.

So it all boils down to deciding whether you prefer complicated, bloated, inconsistant, brittle and insecure code or clean, lean, simple, consistant and (by default) reasonably secure  code. Your choice...